# Media queries not working as expected (Hidden classes Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

On certain breakpoints in the browser I am getting some unexpected results while using Bootstrap (V3.3.7). So I set up a little experiment with the BS hidden classes.

The BS CSS file contains the following CSS for the hidden classes:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .hidden-sm {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .hidden-md {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .hidden-lg {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

I have set up the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Test Bootstrap hidden classes</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .hidden-xs{ color: red; }
        .hidden-sm{ color: blue; }
        .hidden-md{ color: pink; }
        .hidden-lg{ color: green; }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="hidden-xs">Hidden xs</div>
        <div class="hidden-sm">Hidden sm</div>
        <div class="hidden-md">Hidden md</div>
        <div class="hidden-lg">Hidden lg</div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

With the CSS I expect at all time there will be 3 elements visible in my set up. However on window widths 767, 991 and 1199 there are 4 elements present. I tested this in Chrome and Firefox.

I was under the assumption the way media queries in BS are used, is the correct way. Why am I getting this result? Am I missing something or is BS using media queries wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue in my project, so I edited the bootstrap code like this, and it seemed to fix the issue.

```
@media (max-width: 767.99px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.99px) {
  .hidden-sm {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.99px) {
  .hidden-md {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .hidden-lg {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

I think the underlying issue here is that the browsers are measuring out width in fractions of pixels, but the css leaves a 1 pixel gap between the classes.